# How to mix the task and runs_once decorator

Tags: python, fabric

How do you mix the @task and @runs_once decorators in Fabric?

I have a task (check_for_updates) that checks installed Python packages on each host and records which ones need updates. I then have a task (report_pending_updates) that displays a report showing which hosts require updates. So I'm doing:

```
fab production check_for_updates report_pending_updates
```

However, since I have multiple hosts, it runs report_pending_updates for each host, showing the report multiple times.

I've tried constructing my task like:

```
@runs_once
@task
def report_pending_updates():
    ...
```

but this causes Fabric to not detect the task. Switching the decorator order results in the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Put the @task first, otherwise it won't recognize it as such. As for the runs_once, are you running this in parallel, which wouldn't share this runs_once state across the forks?

If so or similar you should look into using execute() to handle this work. Something more like this:

```
def report_pending_updates():
    execute(check_for_updates, hosts=hosts)

    #everything else
    ...
```